# Рисование какой либо фигуры над Image

Tags: c#, wpf

Допустим есть `System.Windows.Controls.Image exampleImage`. Программно в коде, я смотрю на поле `int valueContent` и от состояния данного поля, `> 0`, рисую над `exampleImage` Ellipse. Как можно это реализовать?

Нужен метод только рисования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вы можете положить `Image` в `Grid`, и добавить вторым дочерним элементом в тот же `Grid` ваш эллипс.

Порядок важен: последовательность дочерних элементов определяет их Z-order.

Comment: Естественно необходимо прописывать свой UserContol